# No module named pandas but pandas is already installed in linux

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two python distributions(python2.7,python3.6) and in both I have installed `pandas` and `numpy` as well but cant use

These are the errors caused when i tried to import pandas

**in python 2.7**

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 19, in 
>       "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>
> ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

**then imported numpy**

> ImportError:
>
> Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
>   likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
>   If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
>   files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray

**in python 3.6**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these cases, the problem is that you are installing pandas in another environment. The easy solution here is using Anaconda.

Anaconda is focused on environments. First, you should choose installation of python2 or python3. Then, you can install this version of Anaconda in Linux: https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux
For example:

64-Bit (x86) Installer (622 MB) Python3:

```
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Then you need, install in your system:

```
$ bash Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Be cautious in the interactive dialog in order to install Anaconda. Remember the route of the installation.

When you have Anaconda in a folder named: anaconda 3 (for example). go to route: .../anaconda3/bin.

Now, you should execute:

```
$ source activate
```

Now you are in base environment, you can install the packages that you need (pandas and numpy are install by default). However, I recommend you create a new environment for each new proyect (see https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf).

Imagine that you have (base) environment. In this environment try:

```
$ python
```

The first message gives you the python version. Anyway you can try:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
```

In order to know the version that you are using.